# Mask credentials in Jenkins script shell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I added credentials in Credentials Binding Plugin in Jenkins.
Then I send this credentials as text to company's chat in Execute shell section using curl with data parameter:

```
curl --silent  $url -d "{ \"text\": \"$credentials\" }" -H "X-Auth-Token: $auth_token" -H "X-User-Id: $user_id" -H "Content-type:application/json"
```

And I receive unmasked credentials in chat. How can I mask credentials or modify Binding plugin which will mask secret text same as echo output

Comment: Just to get this straight: You want to send credentiaks to a third party chat software and also want it to be masked?

Comment: Yes. I want it impossible to send credentials to third part software (in particular to the chat). But if you try to send, you will receive in the chat some asterisks "****"

Comment: I don't think that is possible. In order for credentials to work they need to be in plain text somewhere. Just don't send them anywhere or replace them with asterisks yourself. It shouldn't happen too often that you send credentials around anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found a working method to hide credentials to third part software:
1. to make curl wrapper with the same name 'curl' in bash on Jenkins side ${JENKINS_HOME}/bin. This curl wrapper will be filter arguments which contain credentials. Of course origin credentials will be hardcoded in file
2. to compile wrapper using shc 
3. to make jenkins user owner  for created binary file. to set permissions +x and revoke -r and -w
4. to set environments in Jenkins 
PATH=${JENKINS_HOME}/bin:$PATH
So when 'curl' command will be called then the curl wrapper will run instead